# Combine arrays, count values and total in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

After many attempts to crack this I am stuck so I turn to SO for help.

I have two arrays, as below. The keys from both arrays are relational to each other. 
I need to combine both arrays together as a key=>value pair.

for example:

```
[Internet Explorer] => 3
[Internet Explorer] => 2
```

However, following this I need to total the values of the duplicate keys. Resulting in a unique total key=>value pair for each browser.

for example:

```
[Internet Explorer] => 5
[Google Chrome] => 3
```

Thank you for looking, I have tried many array functions and I always come to the same result of getting unique keys without totalised values.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Unknown
    [1] => Unknown
    [2] => Unknown
    [3] => Internet Explorer
    [4] => Internet Explorer
    [5] => Mozilla Firefox
    [6] => Internet Explorer
    [7] => Unknown
    [8] => Unknown
    [9] => Google Chrome
    [10] => Google Chrome
    [11] => Mozilla Firefox
    [12] => Mozilla Firefox
    [13] => Unknown
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 1
    [4] => 1
    [5] => 1
    [6] => 1
    [7] => 1
    [8] => 1
    [9] => 1
    [10] => 1
    [11] => 1
    [12] => 2
    [13] => 1
)
```

Edit: Adding code for clarity.

$agent_list is the result of a query which collects unique instances of USER AGENT and counts them.
The getBrowser function searches each $agents and extracts the browser type.

```
$agents = array();
$agents_count = array();

foreach($agent_list as $value1)
{

    $agent = getBrowser($value1['agent']);
    array_push($agents,$agent); 
    array_push($agents_count,(int)$value1['count']);

}
```

Comment: @Damoe can you please attache require o/p for given example

Comment: Can you post the relevant parts of your existing code to clarify the question and provide a starting point for us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the keys array is `$keys` and the values array is `$values`, this should work.

```
$result = array_fill_keys(array_unique($keys), 0);
foreach($keys as $i=>$k){
   $result[$k] += $values[$i];
}
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/9EIOU

Comment: thanks, the demo really helped me understand. I hadn't tried array_fill_keys.

Comment: You're welcome. `array_fill_keys` is a very useful function :-)

Answer (score 1):

Hope, I understand your question
Let `$a`,`$b` are input arrays, result will be in `$a`

```
foreach($b as $k=>$v){
    if(isset($a[$k]))
        $a[$k]+=$v;
    else
        $a[$k]=$v;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not iterate over one array and add values if they exists or append if they don't exist:

```
foreach($array1 as $key => $value){
    $array2[$key] += $value;
}
```

This will ad the value or add the key with the value if it doesn't exist in `$array2`.